# dockerfile pulling php7.4 instead installing it

Tags: dockerfile

I have this in my dockerfile

FROM  php:7.4-fpm

is there advantage of that than pulling image of ubuntu then install the php7.4 ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> is there advantage of that than pulling image of ubuntu then install the php7.4 ?

Is there an advantage of using `FROM ubuntu` instead of using `FROM scratch` and installing ubuntu?

---

The advantages of using a pre-built base images are faster builds, convenience, deterministic builds as you are re-using the same base layers for all builds instead of re-building every time.